# Ubuntu - Can't execute binaries unless they reside in /var/lib/php/session/

Tags: linux, debian, ubuntu, elf

I noticed this weird issue in a Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic Beaver) box and a couple of other Debian-based systems -- I will take statically linked `netcat` binary (a unix networking tool) for the sake of demonstration, however the result is the same for any other ELF executable.

Executing it gives the following message (from any normal directory such as `/tmp`):

```
/tmp$ ./nc
-bash: ./nc: Permission denied
```

The permissions with `chmod` are correct for execute permissions:

```
/tmp$ ls -lah nc
-rwxr-xr-x 1 user user 2.8M May 19 19:38 nc
```

I have tried lots of combinations, but none worked, until a friend of mine suggested that I put the binary in `/var/lib/php/session` (where PHPSESSIDs reside) and it works:

```
/var/lib/php/session$ ./nc
Ncat: You must specify a host to connect to. QUITTING.
```

However, I have not been able to find an explanation for this yet, and `php` is not present in every system, so what do I do in that case?

Comment: There are much more "normal" directories than /tmp.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I tried a bunch of them (home dir., `/dev/shm`, etc.), but without any luck. Only `/var` worked till now. And by "normal" I mean the ones which I have write permissions as that particular user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens when `/tmp` is mounted with the `noexec` flag, which is probably the case on your system — see the output of `mount`. This prevents any executable stored under `/tmp` from running, regardless of the file’s permissions. The idea behind mounting `/tmp`, and other world-writable directories, with this setting is to make it harder to drop binaries on your system and execute them.

Any directory in a volume mounted *without* `noexec` (such as `/var`, in most cases) can be used to store executables you wish to run. Which directory *you* should use depends on your exact use-case.